# Remove ms word 2013 formatting from text

Tags: javascript, java, character-encoding, ms-word

How do I escape `AutoFormatting code` from `MS Word 2013` copied contents before persistance?
For instance, on persisting `‘this should be ok’` becomes `���this should be ok���` when rendered on the screen.

On the server side it shows as `âPADSOSthis should be okâPADSGCI`.
I had to disable `autoformat` feature in word to resolve this issue. I tried both `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8` encoding without luck.  Its a java based web application.
I am setting the charset type as UTF-8 in the html file.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: that's not "word formatting". that's a character set issue. you've got text in charset "A", and displaying it in an environment that's using charset "B". blindly selecting iso8859/utf8 is pointless - you need to target whatever your display environment's using, or set your environment to be utf8/iso

Comment: @MarcB: I have set the encoding to be UTF-8 in my html file. Are you saying it's not sufficient ?

Comment: you have to use the same charset EVERYWHERE. just because you output some html headers doesn't mean that's what the server will be dealing with, or any background database, etc...

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks for the suggestion. Even after saving the ms word doc in utf-8 encoding, I get the same error. Once I disabled the AutoFormat property that converts 'Straight quotes with smart quotes'  in word 2013, fixed the problem.' Do you still think its encoding related?

Comment: anytime you see `â`, it's an encoding issue

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but Word is substituting the regionally correct quote/apostrophe character for the "straight" one. For most locales with a "Latin" code page I'd expect the ANSI value to fall within the standard 256 characters. Have you checked which ANSI codes these characters are? I'd think, worst case, you could check for them and replace them...

Comment: @CindyMeister - I ended up replacing  the special chars with regular chars in js.